# Convert a Jena ResultSet to Model

Tags: sparql, jena, semantic-web, apache-jena

I'm trying to convert a `ResultSet` to a `Model` in Apache Jena 3.0.

Previously I used the

`ResultSetFormatter.toModel` function, but this seems to have been removed.

What's the best way currently to get a Model (for serialization to JSON-LD and RDF/XML) of the ResultSet?

Comment: Haven't used the API for a long time (since version 2) but there seems to be a [`getResourceModel` in `ResultSet`](https://jena.apache.org/documentation/javadoc/arq/org/apache/jena/query/ResultSet.html#getResourceModel--) itself. Not sure it has the right semantics but the types match up.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`RDFOutput.toModel`

`ResultSetFormatter` operations were deprecated in jena 2.13.0 with placeholders left behind and javadoc referring to `RDFOutput`.

Comment: Hmm there are no placeholders or references to it in https://jena.apache.org/documentation/javadoc/arq/org/apache/jena/query/ResultSetFormatter.html that I can see!

Comment: In 2.13.0 there are.  Did you skip that version?

Comment: I was out of the loop for a bit, would be nice to at least mention the RDFOutput in the most current version though (since it does mention the XML serialization is not RDF, but doesn't provide hints how to get it).

Comment: `ResultSetFormatter` is still documented at http://jena.apache.org/documentation/query/app_api.html

Comment: The documentation will be updated. `RDFOutput.toModel` exists but of course the format is non-standard.