# How can I load a Jena Resultset to Jena Model

Tags: jena

I have written a query on [DBpedia](https://dbpedia.org/sparql).

```
SELECT * WHERE {
    <http://dbpedia.org/resource/London> ?p ?o.
    FILTER (langMatches(lang(?x),"en"))
}
```

And I want to load the results in a Jena model so that I can make queries on them later. How can I do that?

I have checked this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32157314/convert-a-jena-resultset-to-model). But this is not working or maybe I am not getting it properly. Would someone explain it with proper examples?

Comment: Do you want to further queries on the data that the original query touched? If so, use a CONSTRUCT query to get the data. Or make queries on the structure of the result set? If so RDFOutput asModel or encodeAsRDF.

Answer (score 0):

As said in the comments, you can run a first `CONSTRUCT` SPARQL query on DBpedia to get a local model. You can then run a second `SELECT` SPARQL local query on that model.

```
final String dbPediaEndpoint = "https://dbpedia.org/sparql";

final Query remoteQuery = QueryFactory.create("""
        CONSTRUCT {
          ?subject ?predicate ?object .
        }
        WHERE {
          ?subject ?predicate ?object .
          FILTER (?subject = <http://dbpedia.org/resource/London>)
        }""");

final Query localQuery = QueryFactory.create("""
        SELECT ?subject ?object {
           ?subject <http://dbpedia.org/property/populationTotal> ?object
        }""");

try (QueryExecution remoteExecution = QueryExecutionHTTP.service(dbPediaEndpoint, remoteQuery)) {
  Model model = remoteExecution.execConstruct();
  try (QueryExecution localExecution = QueryExecutionFactory.create(localQuery, model)) {
    ResultSet resultSet = localExecution.execSelect();
    ResultSetFormatter.out(System.out, resultSet);
  }
}
```

Note: tested with Apache Jena 4.10.0